# Undo core data managed object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have this code:

```
Store* store = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Store"];
store.name = @"My Company"
...
```

Now the store is managed in the context and will be saved when the context is saved, but I have a button where the user can cancel the form where data is collected. How do I undo or remove this from the context? Or am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, you can use an undo manager.  Or, you could simply use a separate ManagedObjectContext, and do all your changes in there.  If you decide to keep them, save the context.  If not, simply discard it.  A MOC is just a scratch pad for work, and has no impact on the underlying database until saved.

You can't really "detach an entity" but you can cause a managed object to turn back into a fault, losing any changes that have not been saved.

```
[managedObjectContext refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO];
```

Snipped from the documentation...

> If flag is NO, then object is turned into a fault and any pending
>   changes are lost. The object remains a fault until it is accessed
>   again, at which time its property values will be reloaded from the
>   store or last cached state.

Answer (score 12):

Core Data has [built-in support for undo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-207821-TPXREF148), so you can undo individual changes by sending the `-undo` message to the context:

```
[store.managedObjectContext undo];
```

It also supports `-redo`. You can undo all changes up to the most recent save using the `-rollback` method:

```
[store.managedObjectContext rollback]
```

as indicated in @melsam's answer.

Comment: What is the difference between undo and rollback? What is most frequently used?

Comment: @Dude The former reverses a single change, the latter reverses *all* changes up to the previous save. Did you take a look at the documentation that I linked? It'll help. Also read about the undo methods in the [NSManagedObjectContext reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html). I just realized that your question is tagged [tag:iOS], so pay attention to the note in the docs that says you'll need to set up the context's undo manager to enable undo support.

Comment: But if you use undo, is it possible that there might be some other places in the code that save something to the context so when you say undo you might undo the wrong change?

Comment: Is there no easy way of just deattaching an entity from the context when you have the reference to it?

Comment: @Dude You can certainly delete the object. A managed object only makes sense in a managed object context, though, so you can't "detach" it and still have a useable object.

Answer (score 6):

```
[store.managedObjectContext rollback];
```

Answer (score 4):

`Undo` works only when I create a `undoManager`(Swift 5):

```
managedObjectContext.undoManager = UndoManager()
```

After this configuration you can undo a last change:

```
managedObjectContext.undo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could save all data from the user in an array and when the user is ready, you only have to save the array to core data.